# Lua 5.2 metatables and environment

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-5.2

I've got a structure like this:

```
context = {
  pi = math.pi,
  sin = math.sin,
  cos = math.cos,
  tan = math.tan,
  print = print
}

modules = {
  m1 = {
    variables = { x = 1 },
    update = function(self)
      local _ENV = self.variables
      x = 2
      m2.x = 2
    end
  },
  m2 = {
    variables = { x = 1 },
    update = function(self)
      local _ENV = self.variables
    end
  }
}

setmetatable(modules.m1, {__index = modules.m1.variables})
setmetatable(modules.m1.variables, {__index = context})

setmetatable(modules.m2, {__index = modules.m2.variables})
setmetatable(modules.m2.variables, {__index = context})

setmetatable(context, {__index = modules})
```

The idea is that users enter code into a UI and that code is pasted into the `update` functions of the different modules, just after where `local _ENV` is set.  This user-entered code should be sandboxed.  It should be able to access a few functions (the ones in the `context` table) and the contents of other modules.  Code in `m1:update` should be able to refer to variables in `m1.variables` without qualifying them; variables in other modules (ie ones in `m2.variables`) should be accessible by qualifying them with the module name (ie `m2.x`).

But the result I get is this:

```
$ lua -i test.lua
> = modules.m1.x
1
> = modules.m1.variables.x
1
> = modules.m2.x
1
> = modules.m2.variables.x
1
> = modules.m1:update()
> = modules.m1.x
2
> = modules.m1.variables.x
2
> = modules.m2.x
2
> = modules.m2.variables.x
1
```

Why is `modules.m2.variables.x` not getting updated?  And if, as it seems, `modules.m2.x` is different to `modules.m2.variables.x`, then where is `modules.m2.x` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modules.m2.variables.x` is not getting updated because you only set [`__index` metamethod](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html) (which is used when retrieving a non-existing key), but not [`__newindex` metamethod](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.2.html) (which is used when assigning a value to a non-existent key), and as the result the value is stored in `modules.m2.x` table and not `modules.m2.variables.x` table as you intended.

If I add `__newindex` as in `setmetatable(modules.m2, {__index = modules.m2.variables, __newindex = modules.m2.variables})`, I get the expected result.